# disable the escaping function of the backslash in sed

Tags: windows, sed, cmd, escaping, pattern-matching

In GNU sed (and almost all other distributions I know of):

```
SET VAR=C:\nyc
sed "s/PATH/%VAR%/g" file.txt
```

causes any occurrence of PATH to be replaced with a new line followed by "yc". In my case VAR is always a user supplied literal (it's a Windows path). How can I disable the default interpreting of '\'? (I know about hacks like saving VAR in a file and replacing all "\" with "\\" in VAR and then passing it to sed)

Comment: Why not replace all backslashes with double backslashes?

Comment: Yeah it's perfectly possible. The problem is I have many such variables which are also used in "copy" commands, so I'll need to introduce temps for each and stuff which is ugly. I just like to know if this is doable in a single sed command.

Comment: The question seems windows/shell specific, since in no shell that I'm aware of will %VAR% be expanded, and expanding "$VAR" will cause `sed` to omit "C:nyc" rather than a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can modify `%var%` in the Windows command shell:

```
>type file
PATH
PATH

>set var=C:\nyc

>sed "s/PATH/%VAR%/g" file
C:
yc
C:
yc

>set var=%var:\=\\%

>echo %var%
C:\\nyc

>sed "s/PATH/%VAR%/g" file
C:\nyc
C:\nyc
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a useful trick to know and indeed solves the problem somehow by using %VAR:\=\\% in sed instead of %VAR%. Though it seems there simply isn't any way to do this directly in sed without such wizardry.